# Веб парсинг с помощью python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, re

подскажите как с помощью регулярки получить значение DOI: 10.13108/2021-13-1-3 из всего html (пример)

```
<a title="DOI: 10.13108/2021-13-1-3" class=SLink target=_blank href='https://doi.org/10.13108%2F2021-13-1-3'>
```

Попытался сделать так , но все равно не получается

```
 doi = soup.find('a', title=re.compile(r"DOI: 10.13108\/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{1,}-\d{1,}"))
```

Comment: doi = soup.find('a', title="DOI: 10.13108/2021-13-1-3').get('title') А здесь что не так?

Comment: Тут же не полный title , не будет находить

Comment: doi = soup.find('a', title="DOI: 10.13108/2021-13-1-3') А здесь что не так?

Comment: Ну здесь найдет , но имеется же ввиду что  значение будет не постоянным (2021-13-1-3), поэтому пытаюсь с регуляркой сделать

Comment: Все понял, вы ищете по тегу "а" с аттрибутом "title" с "DOI: 10.13108/x" Где x любые значения.

Comment: Да все верно, не сумел как то это сформулировать)

Comment: Так я почти подказал вам 'Где x любые значения". x не важно что там цифры буквы(маленкие или боьшие) знаки припенания нам это не важно.  Нам главно что-бы была ее постоянная часть "DOI: 10.13108/"

Comment: Все равно не догоняю как это сделать

Comment: doi = soup.find('a', title=re.compile(r"DOI: 10.13108")) если я правельно понял из документаций BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Не работает так

Answer (score 0):

как пример

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<a class="SLink" target="_blank" title="DOI: 10.13108/2021-13-1-3" href="https://doi.org/10.13108/2021-13-1-3"></a>
<a class="SLink" target="_blank" title="DOI: 10.13108/2021-15-1-3" href="https://doi.org/10.13108/2021-15-1-3"></a>
<a class="SLink" target="_blank" title="DOI: 10.13008/2021-15-1-3" href="https://doi.org/10.13008/2021-15-1-3"></a>
<a class="SLink" target="_blank" title="DOI: 11.13108/2021-15-1-3" href="https://doi.org/11.13108/2021-15-1-3"></a>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all(title=re.compile("DOI: 10.13108/")))
```

вывод

```
[<a class="SLink" href="https://doi.org/10.13108/2021-13-1-3" target="_blank" title="DOI: 10.13108/2021-13-1-3"></a>,
 <a class="SLink" href="https://doi.org/10.13108/2021-15-1-3" target="_blank" title="DOI: 10.13108/2021-15-1-3"></a>]
```

Comment: Имеется в ввиду во всем html файле а не на конкретном примере

Comment: класс тоже такой есть поэтому значение будет не одно